# Oracle - De/para WebFocus para Oracle

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Galera, gostaria de uma ajuda.

Tenho um ETL que foi criado no WebFocus, e vou migrá-lo para Oracle.

Já fiz boa parte dos de/paras, e gostaria de uma alternativa para as seguintes situações.
No WebFocus, ele consegue utilizar uma coluna anterior, já calculada como parâmetro para calculo de outro valor.

Exemplo:

```
SUM(CASE
   WHEN T1.M2143831 > T1.M2460254
     THEN
       (T1.M2143831 * 100 / T1.M2143833)
     ELSE
       (T1.M2460254 * 100 / T1.M2460256)
END) AS TAXA_L,
SUM(CASE
   WHEN T4.FABRICANTE_ID = 'TESTE'
        AND TAXA_L >= 80
     THEN  1
   ELSE NULL
END) MAIOR80
```

Conforme o exemplo, ele utiliza o **TAXA_L** calculado na etapa anterior, como parâmetro, e no Oracle não consigo fazer isto.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
SUM(CASE
      WHEN T4.FABRICANTE_ID = 'TESTE'
         AND SUM(CASE
                    WHEN T1.M2143831 > T1.M2460254
                    THEN
                        (T1.M2143831 * 100 / T1.M2143833)
                    ELSE
                        (T1.M2460254 * 100 / T1.M2460256)
                 END) >= 80
      THEN
         1
      ELSE
         NULL
END)AS MAIOR80
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Estou quebrando a cabeça com isto, alguma alternativa?

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido utilizando estrutura de CTE. 
[CTE - Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/entry/converting_common_table_expressions_from).

Quebrei a query em duas etapas.

Seguem exemplos:

- [CTE - Exemplo 1](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html)
- [CTE - Exemplo 2](http://www.dbspecialists.com/files/presentations/recursive_common_table_expressions.pdf)